# BAD signature from "Debian CD signing key <debian-cd@lists.debian.org>"

Tags: key, signature, gnupg, verify

debian8 lxde iso file and signature file downloaded.

```
ls
debian-8.8.0-amd64-lxde-CD-1.iso    SHA1SUMS  SHA1SUMS.sign
```

To check it sha1 commands.

```
sha1sum   debian-8.8.0-amd64-lxde-CD-1.iso
28bc1fefa093de96879be36a14b00c4991ce9cec  debian-8.8.0-amd64-lxde-CD-1.iso
grep  'lxde'  SHA1SUMS
28bc1fefa093de96879be36a14b00c4991ce9cec  debian-8.8.0-amd64-lxde-CD-1.iso
```

The two sha1sum strings are same.

```
gpg --keyserver keyring.debian.org --recv 6294BE9B
gpg --verify  SHA1SUMS.sign  debian-8.8.0-amd64-lxde-CD-1.iso
```

An error occur.

```
gpg: Signature made Mon 08 May 2017 02:28:21 AM CST using RSA key ID 6294BE9B
gpg: BAD signature from "Debian CD signing key <debian-cd@lists.debian.org>"
```

1.Why  BAD signature from "Debian CD signing key "?
Is something wrong for the debian public key?

2.It is not a smarty way to get sha1sum with `sha1sum   debian-8.8.0-amd64-lxde-CD-1.iso` and `grep  'lxde'  SHA1SUMS` ,then to compare the two output strings by eyes.

Answer (score 4):

I have just crashed into the same issue when verifying debian-8.8 dvds.

The message of "BAD signature" is from the final line in the file SHA***SUMS, which is an empty line (in my case). Just deleted the empty line in my SHA***SUMS and everything went fine; tried with all SHA1, SHA256, SHA512. That's our own error when copying the content of the file from the browser that by "select all" or "ctrl A", we included the empty line.